# Css Font won't import online

Tags: css, font-face

i have a imported css font with the following code:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: font;
    src: url('myriad pro/myriad pro/MyriadWebPro.ttf'),
    url('myriad pro/myriad pro/MyriadWebPro.ttf');
}
```

The problem is that online doesn't work but locally works.What is causeing the problem

Comment: Is this the real path? With spaces in it?

Comment: i tried src: url('MyriadWebPro.ttf') and i moved the file still doesnt work

Comment: this is way too vague to find a solution...what browser are you using? are those files/folders hosted online as well?

Comment: If the problem is that it does not work online, post the URL of the online page.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the file path, for example ---> "myriad-pro/myriad-pro/MyriadWebPro.ttf". Is your  css file in the folder with the font. Check if your path is right.

P.S: Remove the bottom url (that on the third line.). When I use font-face I use only two. Example: `font-family: Consolas;
        src: url('Consolas.ttf');`

Comment: Try this tool: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator It might help you. Check this out too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9897306/font-face-not-working

Answer (score 0):

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: MyriadPro; /* just declares a font in your stylesheet */
    src: url('myriad pro/myriad pro/MyriadWebPro.ttf'),
    url('myriad pro/myriad pro/MyriadWebPro.ttf');
}

body 
{
    /* now you need to use it */
    font-family: MyriadPro, sans-serif;
    /* so name it something useful, instead of just "font" */
}
```

answering old questions

for those who come looking after

Comment: For those who come looking after, can you please explain what you've changed and how it fixes the problem?

Comment: the question itself isn't clear, it does omit the portion of the code where the @font-face is used

Comment: my example includes the body element where the defined $font-face is used